# How i can resolve all parameters the costructor

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest, http

i'm having a little problem.
I try to insert in the constructor of the dialog

```
constructor(private postservices: PostServices)
```

the file ts where there are the rest Api, when I add it on the browser I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DialogComponent: (?, [object Object], [object Object]).
```

having already imported httpCLientModule into app.module.ts

Comment: Seems like some problem with either export of your PostServices of DialogComponent. Can you add initial codes of those 2 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you correctly setted the service in the providers part of the module file? I show you an example from the documentation (https://angular.io/guide/providers):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { UserService } from './user.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {
}
```